# windows phone mvvm with sensors

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, sensors

I'm learning MVVM with the hope of developing an app that uses the phone's sensors, such as accelerometer or gps, but I can't find any good samples or tutorials for using sensors with MVVM.  I'm just not sure whether the code that handles getting the updated data from the sensors should be a model, view, view model, or something other than that, if adherence to MVVM doesn't restrict you to the use of only models, views, and view models.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly branch out from just Model, View, and ViewModel.  I typically have either a "utility" or "service" set of classes to support my application.

Once you have those classes, you can use a lightweight messaging (such as is provided in MVVM Light) to pass sensor readings to your ViewModel.